# air push notification with Android GCM and Fresh Planet extension

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, air-native-extension

I'm using Fresh Planet's AIR Push Notification extension for Android and iOS. Everyone's saying it works ok but I cannot make it work with Android.

I instanciate the extension properly, and I try to register my device on GCM as they say in the documentation, calling...

```
PushNotification.getInstance().registerForPushNotification("myAPPid");
```

it works OK because I can see in LogCat the next lines:

```
c2dmRegister(23756): C2DMRegisterFunction.call 464122159769
c2dmRegister(23756): intent with extras PendingIntent{41284dc8: android.os.BinderProxy@412745c8} ... 464122159769
```

but, nothing happens after that. Receiver class is never called and thus, as3 callback never called...

i don't know what else to do.

Thanks in advance, 
Paula.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "air." in front the application id in the corresponding android manifest was what made it work for me.

Also see https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification/issues/11